# Can an external website have access to Cordova/Phonegap plugins?

Tags: cordova

I would like my app to view an HTML file lives on a webserver (not locally). How can I reference the cordova.js in this HTML file so it can have access to phonegap plugins (eg: GPS, Camera, storage).

Comment: Why don't you build a very basic cordova app, that simply downloads your HTML file from your server and displays it? I'm not sure if you can access phonegap plugins, but i would give it a try

Comment: I have a large existing app that have a lot of relative urls to external html, css, js and back-end API's. Simply downloading the HTML and rendering it to the screen will break these relative URLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call to phonegap plugins via local code, if you want to display external files, you can use iframes, inapp browser plugin, or download the code to display from the server, and display locally. And make the calls from the internal code.

Happy coding

Comment: I was actually able to upload the static cordova JS files to a webserver and use the GPS plugin on my external site. Even though it works, I'm not sure if I'm using phonegap the way it was intended to be used. If I continue down on this path, I'm afraid of heading down a painful path that I may regret.